# IBM Support Assistant Out Of Memory when opening heapdump .phd file

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-6.1

I am using IBM Support Assistant 5 on my local machine. I am trying to open a heapdump file (.phd) file that I have grabbed from the server where I've had an out of memory error and copied it to my local machine. The file size is 915 MB.

Inside IBM Support Assistant I am using the Memory Analyzer tool (desktop). When I launch this tool there is a screen which allows you to specify the min heap and max heap. I have played around with trying to increase the maximum heap size from 1024 to 7500 but no matter what I do with these settings I get an outOfMemoryError in the tool after it spends x minutes trying to parse the heap dump.

[image]

I am running Windows 7 with the following JVM.

```
java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode, sharing)
```

The heapdump was created on a WebSphere 6.1 server.

Can someone please suggest to me a way that I can work through this so as to be able to open and analyze the heap dump.

Comment: How much RAM do you have in your machine? How big was the heap on the server (max heap setting)? You can always try stand alone [heap dump analyzer](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=4544bafe-c7a2-455f-9d43-eb866ea60091)

Comment: The stand alone version version for me worked! Thanks. I didn't even have to change any memory settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have trouble running memory analyzer from ISA, you can download and run standalone version - [Heap dump analyzer](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=4544bafe-c7a2-455f-9d43-eb866ea60091)

Answer (score 1):

In order to process a heapdump or core/system dump with Memory Analyzer, you typically need as much configured heap space (-Xmx) as the application the dump was taken from, so if your server application had an -Xmx of 5G, then you will likely need that for Memory Analyzer too.

Secondly, Memory Analyzer in ISA 5 runs as a separate application to ISA 5 itself, so you need to ensure you increase the maximum heap size for Memory Analyzer specifically. This is found in the following directory:

```
ISA5\wlp\usr\servers\com.ibm.java.web.memoryanalyzer
```

Comment: Really...you have to go to another directory? Then why does it ask you to specify the heap size when you launch the analyzer?